# float right and hr alignment

Tags: css

I got the following code:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <a href="#" style="height: 10px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid black;">MY BUTTON</a>
    <hr />
</div>
```

When I use float right in the button, the hr goes up. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I wasn't kidding. You said, _When I use float right in the button_. What button?

Comment: @j08691 If you can't deduce by yourself I fell sorry for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `clear`ing it.

```
hr
{
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what you are doing, I think you are trying to compound a button.

I recommend to remove '<'br'/>' and add into the '<'a'>' style this: 'line-height:100px;'